# Parser the call of a function - FParsec

Tags: f#, fparsec

I try to parse the call of a function, here are the variants:

```
add 8 2
add x y
add (inc x) (dec y)
funcWithoutArgs
```

Depending on how I distribute my analyzers in the code, and perhaps also how they are coded, I get errors, as well as successful but unwanted analyses.
For example, this:

```
add 4 7
```

returns the following AST:

```
[Call ("foo",[Number 4]);
 Number 7]
```

He therefore only takes the first parameter.

When I do that:

```
foo x y
```

He sends me back this AST:

```
[Call ("foo",[Call ("x",[Call ("y",[])])])]
```

And that's not what I want, since here, each parameter calls the next one as a parameter.

Another example, when I do this:

```
foo x y
inc x
```

I get:

```
[Call ("foo",[Call ("x",[Call ("y",[Call ("inc",[Call ("x",[])])])])])]
```

It does the same as above, but also calls the code that follows the line. When I ask my analyzer for a new line (see code), it sends me this:

```
[Call ("foo",[]); Call ("x",[]); Call ("y",[]); Call ("inc",[]); Call ("x",[])]
```

Even in brackets it doesn't work:

```
foo (x) (y)
```

Give:

```
[Call ("foo",[]); Call ("x",[]); Call ("y",[])]
```

And:

```
add (inc x) (dec y)
```

Give:

```
Error in Ln: 1 Col: 1
Note: The error occurred on an empty line.

The parser backtracked after:
  Error in Ln: 2 Col: 5
  add (inc x) (dec y)
      ^
  Expecting: end of input or integer number (32-bit, signed)

  The parser backtracked after:
    Error in Ln: 2 Col: 10
    add (inc x) (dec y)
             ^
    Expecting: ')'

[]
```

In short, my function call analyzer does not work properly. Every time I change something, like a new line, an attempt, or a different hierarchy, something doesn't work...
Do you have any idea how to solve this very annoying problem?

Here is the minimum functional code that was used:

```
open FParsec

// Ast

type Expression =
    | Number of int
    | Call of string * Expression list

type Program = Expression list

// Tools

let private bws p =
    spaces >>? p .>>? spaces

let private suiteOf p =
    sepEndBy p spaces1

let inline private betweenParentheses p label =
    between (pstring "(") (pstring ")") p
    <?> (label + " between parentheses")

let private identifier =
    many1Satisfy2 isLetter (fun c -> isLetter c)

// Expressions

let rec private call = parse {
        let! call = pipe2 (spaces >>? identifier) (spaces >>? parameters)
                        (fun id parameters -> Call(id, parameters)) // .>>? newline
        return call
    }

and private parameters = suiteOf expression

and private callFuncWithoutArgs =
    identifier |>> fun id -> Call(id, [])

and private number = pint32 |>> Number

and private betweenParenthesesExpression =
    parse { let! ex = betweenParentheses expression "expression"
            return ex }

and private expression =
    bws (attempt betweenParenthesesExpression <|>
         attempt number <|>
         attempt call <|>
         callFuncWithoutArgs)

// -------------------------------

let parse code =
    let parser = many expression .>>? eof

    match run parser code with
        | Success(result, _, _) -> result
        | Failure(msg, _, _) ->
            printfn "%s" msg
            []

System.Console.Clear()

parse @"
add 4 7

foo x y

inc x

foo (x) (y)

add (inc x) (dec y)

" |> printfn "%A"
```

Comment: First question: why do you want `funcWithoutArgs` to be parsed as a *function call* rather than as an *identifier*? In every language I'm aware of, calling a function requires different syntax than referring to it: e.g., `func()` is a function call, while `func` is simply a reference to the function. I think part (though not all) of your problem may be stemming from the fact that `funcWithoutArgs` is parsing as a function call.

Comment: Second question: you state that `[Call ("foo",[Call ("x",[Call ("y",[])])])]` is *not* what you want `foo x y` to parse to, but I can't tell from the types in your example what you *would* want `foo x y` to parse to. I would assume you would want it to parse to something like `[Call ("foo", [Identifier "x"; Identifier "y"])]`, but there's no `Identifier` in the DU in your pared-down example. So what do you want `foo x y` to actually parse to? What's your actually desired result?

Comment: @rmunn First answer: `funcWithoutArgs` is, as its name suggests, supposed to be a function call, without arguments, which can be seen as a simple identifier, in fact. For example, in OCaml, Haskell or even F#, there is, as far as I know, no distinction, since the variables/data are simply data that can be applied.  That's what I've been trying to replicate. What would you have suggested? Maybe to create a new `Variable` node?

Comment: Second answer: in fact, `foo x y` should be analyzed as follows: `[call ("foo",[Call ("x", []); call ("y", []))]`. According to what I said above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main problem is that you have the wrong high-level design for your parser.

Your current design is that an expression can be:

1. An expression (a "sub-expression", so to speak) between parentheses (no problem here)
2. A number (no problem here)
3. A call with parameters, which is an identifier followed by a space-separated list of expressions (this is the main part of the problem)
4. A call without parameters, which is a single identifier (this contributes to the problem)

Looking at the expression `foo x y`, let's apply those rules in order as a parser would. There are no parentheses and `foo` isn't a number, so it's either 3 or 4. First we try 3. `foo` is followed by `x y`: does `x y` parse as an expression? Why, yes, it does: it parses as a call with parameters, where `x` is the function and `y` is the parameter. Since `x y` matches 3, it parses according to rule 3 without checking rule 4, and so `foo x y` matches like `foo (x y)` would: a call to `foo` with a single parameter, which is a call to `x` with parameter `y`.

How to fix this? Well, you could try swapping the order of 3 and 4, so that a function call without parameters is checked before a call with parameters (which would make `x y` parse as just `x`. But that would fail, because `foo x y` would match as just `foo`. So putting rule 4 before rule 3 doesn't work here.

The real solution is to split the rules for an expression apart into two levels. The "inner" level, which I'll call a "value", could be:

1. An expression between parentheses
2. A number
3. A function call without parameters

And the "outer" level, the parse rules for expressions, would be:

1. A function call *with* parameters, all of which are *values*, **not** expressions
2. A value

Note that these parsing levels are mutually recursive, so you'll need to use `createParserForwardedToRef` in your implementation. Let's look at how `foo x y` would be parsed with this design:

First, `foo` parses as an identifier, so check if it could be a function call with parameters. Does `x` parse as a value? Yes, under rule 3 of values. And does `y` parse as a value? Yes, under rule 3 of values. So `foo x y` parses as a function call.

Now what about `funcWithoutParameters`? It would fail rule 1 of expressions because it's not followed by a list of parameters. So it would be checked for rule 2 of expressions, and then it would match under rule 3 of values.

Okay, a basic sanity check of the pseudocode works, so let's turn this into code. But first, I'll mention the *other* problem in your parser which I haven't mentioned yet, which is that you don't realize that the FParsec `spaces` parser [also matches newlines](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/charparsers.html#members.spaces). So when you wrap your `expression` parser in `bws` ("between whitespace"), it will also consume newlines after the text it parses. So when you're parsing something like:

```
foo a b
inc c
```

The `suiteOf expression` sees the list `a b inc c` and turns all of those into parameters for `foo`. In my code below I've distinguished between FParsec's `spaces` parser (which includes newlines) and a parser that parses *only* horizontal whitespace (space and tab but not newline), using each in the appropriate place. The following code implements the design I mentioned in this answer and its output looks right to me for all the test expressions you wrote:

```
open FParsec

// Ast

type Expression =
    | Number of int
    | Call of string * Expression list

type Program = Expression list

// Tools

let private justSpaces  = skipMany  (pchar ' ' <|> pchar '\t')
let private justSpaces1 = skipMany1 (pchar ' ' <|> pchar '\t')

let private bws p =
    spaces >>? p .>>? spaces

let private suiteOf p =
    sepEndBy1 p (justSpaces1)

let inline private betweenParentheses p label =
    between (pstring "(") (pstring ")") p
    <?> (label + " between parentheses")

let private identifier =
    many1Satisfy2 isLetter (fun c -> isLetter c)

// Expressions

let private expression, expressionImpl = createParserForwardedToRef()

let private betweenParenthesesExpression =
    parse { let! ex = betweenParentheses expression "expression"
            return ex }

let private callFuncWithoutArgs =
    (identifier |>> fun id -> Call(id, []))

let private number = pint32 |>> Number

let private value =
    justSpaces >>? (attempt betweenParenthesesExpression <|>
                    attempt number <|>
                    callFuncWithoutArgs)

let private parameters = suiteOf value

let rec private callImpl = parse {
        let! call = pipe2 (justSpaces >>? identifier) (justSpaces >>? parameters)
                          (fun id parameters -> Call(id, parameters))
        return call }

let call = callImpl

expressionImpl.Value <-
    bws (attempt call <|>
         value)

// -------------------------------

let parse code =
    let parser = many expression .>>? (spaces >>. eof)

    match run parser code with
        | Success(result, _, _) -> result
        | Failure(msg, _, _) ->
            printfn "%s" msg
            []

System.Console.Clear()

parse @"
add 4 7

foo x y

inc x

foo (x) (y)

add (inc x) (dec y)
" |> printfn "%A"
```

P.S. I used the following operator suggested by http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/users-guide/debugging-a-parser.html to greatly help me in tracing the problem:

```
let (<!>) (p: Parser<_,_>) label : Parser<_,_> =
    fun stream ->
        printfn "%A: Entering %s" stream.Position label
        let reply = p stream
        printfn "%A: Leaving %s (%A)" stream.Position label reply.Status
        reply
```

Usage: turn `let parseFoo = ...` into `let parseFoo = ... <!> "foo"`. Then you'll get a stream of debugging output in your console that looks something like this:

```
(Ln: 2, Col: 20): Entering expression
(Ln: 3, Col: 1): Entering call
(Ln: 3, Col: 5): Entering parameters
(Ln: 3, Col: 5): Entering bwParens
(Ln: 3, Col: 5): Leaving bwParens (Error)
(Ln: 3, Col: 5): Entering number
(Ln: 3, Col: 6): Leaving number (Ok)
(Ln: 3, Col: 7): Entering bwParens
(Ln: 3, Col: 7): Leaving bwParens (Error)
(Ln: 3, Col: 7): Entering number
(Ln: 3, Col: 8): Leaving number (Ok)
(Ln: 3, Col: 8): Leaving parameters (Ok)
(Ln: 3, Col: 8): Leaving call (Ok)
(Ln: 3, Col: 8): Leaving expression (Ok)
```

That helps greatly when you're trying to figure out why your parser isn't doing what you expect.